# How to call RPC using WebSocket in Godot 4.1 | browser multiplayer game (websocket + webRTC) (Attempt to call RPC with unknown peer ID)

Tags: websocket, rpc, godot, gdscript, godot4

I've been trying to make a browser based game (html5 export) that would have main lobby where players can walk around and chat, with minigames that would be solo or co-op...
I've managed to setup the server following a tutorial and started tweaking it (https://youtu.be/ulfGNtiItnc?si=fvJbxVO1NcsSaaSk)
Sending packets works fine for chat messages, but when i try to spawn a player avatar rpc is only called on server.
The hierarchy is the same on all instances of Godot

Control

- Client
- - PlayerSpawn
- Server
- - PlayerSpawn

my Server.gd

```godot
#Adds player scene, name=id is used for taking control in player controller script
@rpc("any_peer", "call_local")
func addNewPlayer(id):
    var currentPlayer = PlayerScene.instantiate()
    currentPlayer.name = str(id)
    get_tree().root.add_child(currentPlayer)
    currentPlayer.global_position = $PlayerSpawn.global_position
    pass

#Adds all existing player scenes for player that joined later
@rpc("any_peer", "call_local")
func addExistingPlayers(idExcluded):
    for key in users:
        var user = users[key]
        if idExcluded == user.id:
            continue
        addNewPlayer(user.id)

#As for calling the RPC, the packets are polled in _process and parsed into string and called like so:
#Only sending this to the new player
addExistingPlayers.rpc_id(int(data.id), data.id)
addNewPlayer.rpc(data.id)
```

my Client.gd

```godot
#I create websocket peer
var peer_socket = WebSocketMultiplayerPeer.new()
#and once client gets assigned ID from the server after connecting this is run
multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = peer_socket

#As for sending the packet to the server
var message = {
    "message": Utilities.PacketMessage.AVATAR_SPAWN,
    "id": id
}
peer_socket.put_packet(JSON.stringify(message).to_utf8_buffer())
```

Despite successful connection, the server doesn't know about any client even though it sent them their unique IDs

EDIT:
1st: upon re-reading docs, "For a remote call to be successful, the sending and receiving node need to have the same NodePath, which means they must have the same name"... sooo does this mean i NEED to have 2 projects... one for server stuff and one for client stuff and in the server one (since i want server authority) i will spawn the players and in the client one the scripts will be named the same but the @rpc funcs will be blank?
OR because it still doesn't make sense to me, considering my current project has both the scripts, yet Server.gd seems to be only working on the HOST instance of godot
2nd: I tried making 2 projects, one for server, one client.. and the RPC still doesnt work with WebSocket peer connection

Answer (score 0):

So turns out im just stupid...
You can do rpc calls with WebSockets, however, in godot 4 you need to make sure the path to the node is the same and that the both projects let's say have also all the @rpc methods. They don't need to have anything in them just the declaration and "pass"
So the reason this didn't work was because the @rpc funcs in server script tried to call @rpc in other server script but they couldn't because the other server script or the client's one didn't have a peer created so there was no id for that...
Simply put let's say you are trying to do server authentication and you have Gateway server between your client and authentication

```godot
#Your Gateway.gd in client project can look like this
#This will only be called from client using testRPC_Client.rpc()
@rpc("any_peer")
func testRPC_Client():
    print("testRPC_Client")
    
#This will only be called from gateway using testRPC_Gate.rpc()
@rpc("any_peer")
func testRPC_Gate():
    #You can put ANYTHING HERE
    pass

#And your Gateway.gd in Gateway project will have to then contain these methods
#This will only be called from client using testRPC_Client.rpc()
@rpc("any_peer")
func testRPC_Client():
    #You can put ANYTHING HERE
    pass

#This will only be called from gateway using testRPC_Gate.rpc()
@rpc("any_peer")
func testRPC_Gate():
    print("testRPC_Gate")
```

Also make sure the annotations use the same parameters or the checksum will fail